# Laravel Foreign key 'student_id' doesn't have a default value , even though it is in request

Tags: laravel, default-value, insert-update

**Migration:**

```
Schema::create('students_detail', function (Blueprint $table) {
           $table->increments('id');
           $table->unsignedInteger('student_id');
           $table->integer('lessons')->nullable();
           $table->string('tests',200)->nullable();

           $table->timestamps();

           $table->foreign('student_id')->references('id')->on('students')

       });
```

**Controller**:

```
public function update(Request $request, StudentsDetail $studentsDetail)
   {
       $student_id= $request->input('student_id');
       $studentsDetail->update($request->except('student_id'));
       $studentsDetail->save();


       return redirect()->back();
   }
```

i tried setting mysql strict to false , it didn't solve my error , NOTE: I can't make column `'student_id'` nullable because it is a foreign key , so while updating this error appears? I don't know how to get rid of it!

Answer (score 2):

Add student_id in you model file protected $fillable array like:

```
 protected $fillable = ['student_id'];
```

Save code on controller:

```
$attributes = $request->all(); // print_r($request->all()) this request and check have you got student_id fields?
$studentsDetail->update($attributes);
return redirect()->back();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass it to the update method :

```
public function update(Request $request, StudentsDetail $studentsDetail)
{
    $studentsDetail->update($request->all());
    $studentsDetail->save();


    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: Still the same error @Maraboc , its strange because when I dd($request->all()); the column 'student_id' is passed there o.O

Comment: What about adding `protected $fillable = ['student_id'];` in the `StudentsDetail` model ?